# Appending svg of d3 chart to separate divs when there are multiple json files

Tags: d3.js, charts, reactjs

So I just started using d3 chart and reactjs. 
I have successfully implemented the charts with different json files but now the prob is all the charts are in one div. I want to separate them so I could use a heading to each chart but what happens is:

For example:

In my code:

```
<h1> Chart A </h1>
<BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/data1.json"/> //first chart
<h1> Chart B </h1>
<BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/data2.json"/> //second chart
<h1> Chart C </h1>
<BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/data3.json"/> //third chart
```

What's actually rendered on my browser:

```
<h1> Chart A </h1>
<div class="baryearChart>
<svg> Chart 1
<svg> Chart 2
<svg> Chart 3
</div>
<h1> Chart B </h1>
<h1> Chart C </h1>
```

### Anyone knows a way to do this? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Here's my chart

```
  render: function() {
    return (
          <div className="baryearChart" style={baryearContainer}>
          </div>
    );
  }
});

var svg = d3.select(".baryearChart").insert("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Then the reactjs page where I called it to display 3 same charts but with diff json files.

```
 <div className="tile-body">
                 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DPWH </h2>
                 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--dpwh.json" id="chart1"/>
                 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DA </h2>
                 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--da.json" id="chart2"/>
                 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DSWD </h2>
                 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--dswd.json" id="chart3"/>
                 <h6 style={{float:'right',fontSize:'14px',fontStyle:'italic'}}> *of Contracts procured through public bidding </h6>
              </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share a bit more of your javascript code? At first glance, i think you just append every svg to the same div, but i ll be able to tell you more if can see some code :-)

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for your reply. I actually used d3 and reactjs.

I will now edit the question so you can see :) @ocket-san

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your response. Thanks to my boss, I figure out already how it works. So what I did was I assigned specific IDs to every chart I call in my page.

In my chart.js

```
var BarYearChart = module.exports = React.createClass({
  chart: null,

  onWindowResize: function() {
    //this.chart.update();
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.chart = new d3BarYearChart(this.props.sourceUrl, this.props.div_id);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function(/*prevProps, prevState*/) {
    // this.chart.setData(this.props);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (

          <div className="baryearChart" id={"barChart_" + this.props.div_id} style={baryearContainer}>
          </div>
    );
  }
});

var d3BarYearChart = function(sourceUrl, div_id) {

    // Var declaration.
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(6);

  var svg = d3.select("#barChart_" + div_id).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Then in my index page

```
<div className="tile-body">
 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DPWH </h2>
 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--dpwh.json" div_id="chart1"/>
 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DA </h2>
 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--da.json" div_id="chart2"/>
 <h2 className="chart-title" style={{borderBottom:'1.5px solid #aaaaaa',paddingBottom:'10px'}}> DSWD </h2>
 <BarYearChart sourceUrl="data/effectiveness--all--dswd.json" div_id="chart3"/>
  <h6 style={{float:'right',fontSize:'14px',fontStyle:'italic'}}> *of Contracts procured through public bidding </h6>
</div>
```

This removed the trouble of appending my svg on the same div. Now I could have each barchart have their own divs so I could put other elements in between them like headings. :)

Answer (score 0):

d3.select() always returns the first element matching the query, so it will give you the first instance of the div with class "baryearChart".

Instead you could try something like:

```
let node = React.findDOMNode(this);
d3.select(node).insert("svg")
// etc...
```

This will insert the SVG into the main node of this specific React component instance. In React 0.14, use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).

Comment: This is quite unclear. Should I put this on the chart.js like?

let node = React.findDOMNode(this);
  var svg = d3.select(node).insert("svg")

Comment: I tried using <svg> </svg> instead but the problem seems to come from the arrays of chart

Comment: Here's some example code: https://gist.github.com/hollandmatt/115b7d3beb3a8b179205